# Testing redux form fails - typeError formProps.handleSubmit is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form, enzyme

I have a component where I use [redux form](https://redux-form.com/7.0.3/) to which I pass redux form props like this:

```
export const UttakInfoPanel = ({
  submitValidation,
  ...formProps
})
```

I am passing a `submitValidation` function to a redux form `handleSubmit` function like this:

```
<form onSubmit={formProps.handleSubmit(submitValidation)}>
```

Submit validation works fine.
I have also made a test for that component:

```
it('will show InfoPanel', () => {
    const formProps = {
      handleSubmit: sinon.spy,
      error: {},
    };

    const wrapper = shallowWithIntl(<InfoPanel
      submitValidation={sinon.spy()}
      formProps={formProps}
    />);
  });
```

But, when I am running my test I get:

> TypeError: formProps.handleSubmit is not a function

Why am I getting this error, when also on the inspecting the `formProps` in the console I can see that `handleSubmit` is a function. How can I make this test pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using rest operator the last parameter will have a type of Array, try to remove spread from UttakInfoPanel component.